# Adding references in Roslyn. ERROR: FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly

Tags: c#, roslyn

Roslyn could not load assembly, despite of using `CreateFromStream` or `CreateFromFile` methods. Here is the error:

> FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SimpleLibrary,
> Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. The system
> cannot find the file specified.

Here is my code:

```
List<MetadataReference> references = new List<MetadataReference>();

Stream stream = File.OpenRead(@"d:\SimpleLibrary.dll");
references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromStream(stream));

string code = @"
using SimpleLibrary;
namespace RoslynCompileSample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public bool Main()
        {
              return true;
        }

    }
}";

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    try
    {
        EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());
            Type type = assembly.GetType("RoslynCompileSample.Program");

            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var MethodOutput = type.InvokeMember("Main",
                    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                    null,
                    obj,
                    null);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

}
```

Comment: The problem is at the Assembly.Load, right? So this isn't anything to do with CreateFromStream -- it's that .NET can't find your assembly you loaded from.

Comment: @JasonMalinowski the stream is ok. i converted it to assembly and it was Ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is `FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'SimpleLibrary...`. Therefore, we should look for a method to load the assembly.

The `SimpleLibrary` assembly can be added to a scope by `AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream` method as follow:

```
Stream stream = File.OpenRead(@"d:\SimpleLibrary.dll");
AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(stream);
```

Here is the code:

```
List<MetadataReference> references = new List<MetadataReference>();

Stream stream = File.OpenRead(@"d:\SimpleLibrary.dll");
references.Add(MetadataReference.CreateFromStream(stream));

string code = @"
using SimpleLibrary;
namespace RoslynCompileSample
{
    public class Program
    {
        public bool Main()
        {
              return true;
        }

    }
}";

using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    try
    {
        EmitResult result = compilation.Emit(ms);
        if (result.Success)
        {
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            Assembly assembly = Assembly.Load(ms.ToArray());

            stream = File.OpenRead(@"d:\SimpleLibrary.dll");
            AssemblyLoadContext.Default.LoadFromStream(stream);

            Type type = assembly.GetType("RoslynCompileSample.Program");

            object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(type);
            var MethodOutput = type.InvokeMember("Main",
                    BindingFlags.Default | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod,
                    null,
                    obj,
                    null);

        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
    }

}
```